# NFC tag scan only triggers my app to start

Tags: android, nfc

I have an app that scans NFC tags, collects the data from the tag and sends that data to the server. The data on the tag is in the following format:

```
1,3,30012,somebodys name
```

These tags are placed in client's houses for carers to scan. Each scan logs them into a call.

This has been working fine so far. The problem i have now is that the carers must use another app alongside our app which scans a different NFC tag, with different data on it and sends it to a different server. This app is installed on the same carer's phone.

This other app will scan NFC tags that might have data on it in the following format:

```
abc|123??
```

The question is how can i ensure that when the carer scans our tag, ONLY our app is launched?

Is there a way in the manifest of specifying this in the intent-filters for my app?

This is what i have in the manifest for my Activity. I understand that if an Intent is launched and there are 2 apps that could process an NFC tag then a list is presented to the user. The Android docs discourage against this.

Thanks in advance.

[Edit]
One thing i have noticed, if the phone is on the home screen and i scan a tag, then my app is launched. This is fine if the carer scans the correct tag.

```
<activity android:name=".NfcscannerActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.QRCODE_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom mimeType in your NDEF message and then create an intent-filter which matches it exactly. This would mean your app would be launched as it is the most specific filter.

Example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.my.app.package.customString" />
</intent-filter>
```

Edit:
Alternatively if you cannot create a custom mimeType then perhaps your utility will create a custom URL? Then you can create a filter for the custom url instead:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.mywebsite.net" 
                android:path="/customPathForAction" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. At the moment when i create the tags, i write the data to the tag using a tagwriter app and specify 'Plain text'. How would i write the mimetype to the tag so my app can filter for it?

Comment: You may try the app "NFC Tools". This allows to create custom types.

Comment: @corvairjo Hi i've downloaded the app but it is not obvious how to do this. Do i click on Data-add a custom record. Then in the content-type add application/vnd.com.my.app.package.customString?

Comment: I've added an alternative approach using a custom url in case you can't create a cutom mimeType with your utility. See Edit.

Comment: If you want to use the mentioned form of "application/vnd.com.my.app.package.customString", then put "application" into the first field (where the grey text states "text") and put "vnd.com.my.app.package.customString" into the second field (where the grey text states "plain").

Comment: @jgriffin i've tried to write the a tag with a custom mime-type but the tag is MiFare ultralight and can only hold 46 bytes. I do have another tag with a larger 500 bytes capacity but it crashes my app as there is an error parsing the records on the tag. The tag is nfcA type. the ultralight are type 2 tags. To avoid changing code could i buy some miFare ultralight C tags with a 144 byte capacity. Would my code process the tags in the same way as the ultralights with 46 bytes capacity?

Comment: @turtleboy yeah I think that would work. The Ultralight c are "ISO/IEC 14443 parts 1-3, Type A" compliant so they should work with the same code. Don't hold me to ransom on that though as I've come across many strange exceptions when working on NFC in Android.