# Android NFC AAR(s) Without Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm trying to make an NFC tag that performs all of the necessary installation and start up for my application.  Basically, the idea is you take our device out of the box, touch your phone to it, and it walks you through all the steps to install it and run it.  Then, at any time in the future, you can just touch the NFC tag and go.

On the tag, I would like to have:

1. Uri record pointing to our website's downloads page,
2. Bluetooth related records for pairing our device with the phone
3. AAR containing our application package name

If our application is installed, this works great, as we receive the NDEF intent, parse the bluetooth and pair the remote device.

If our application is not installed, I would like a browser to open our website so you can download the app.  Unfortunately, the presence of the AAR NDEF record instead sends the user to the Google Play Store.  For business reasons, we don't want to put our app onto the play store at this time.

Is there a way to have an AAR or equivalent record on the tag that directs the intent to our app if installed, but that doesn't redirect to the app store if not installed?

Failing that, is there a solution with multiple AAR records that can fallback to a browser when our app is not installed?

Comment: While I really wish this were possible, AFAIK it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're still looking for a better answer, but here's the best we've come up with so far.

Our tag now contains:

1. Uri record pointing to our website's downloads page,
2. Bluetooth related records for pairing our device with the phone
3. AAR containing our application package name
4. AAR containing com.sec.android.app.sbrowser
5. AAR containing com.google.android.browser
6. AAR containing com.android.chrome

Basically, if our app is installed, our app catches the intent, otherwise we try several standard browser package names as fallbacks to catch the uri.  We have a fairly large NFC tag, so maybe we can make a list of all the standard browser package names on android.

So far it works on 8 phones from 4 different manufacturers.  If anyone has a full list of browsers, we'd appreciate it.  Its obviously not ideal, but it might work for enterprise scenarios where you can control which phones to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Drop all AAR records and create an intent-filter in your app's manifest to exactly filter for the specific URI. Then if your app is installed it will always receive the intent, otherwise whatever app/browser is installed on the phone to handle generic http/https will open the download page.

Please view a previous answer of mine which demonstrates creating a custom URI/MimeType filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27397938/3312868

EDIT: In time, if you publish your app on the Play Store, you can alter your download url to redirect to the Play Store.

Comment: Does the filter have to be an exact match?  I've found on my test phone that just supplying the host name is not enough to route to my app directly, the user is always whether to start the browser or my app.

Comment: The most specific intent-filter should "win". Did you try adding a wildcard as the path?

Comment: Additionally in the docs the android:path is actually android:pathPrefix, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#abs-uri

Comment: I set an intent filter for NDEF_DISCOVERED that matches scheme https, host <mywebsite>, pathPrefix /downloads, with a category of DEFAULT.  My test phone still asks me whether or not I want to use chrome when my app is installed.