# Launch a specific android app with NFC

Tags: android, nfc, launch

I want to launch a specific android app through a NFC card. I don't want android to ask me which app should be opened. It should instantly open my app. How could I do that?

I already tried it with `MIME-Types` but it did not work. Could i specify my own `MIME-Type`? Would it be possible to check the `MIME-Type` text/plain for a specific text(intent filter?)?

For example: I want my app to start when the NFC card has a specific text stored like "test" or something.

The idea is that it should work on every common mobile OS. Therefore an android application link would not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Specific App when NFC is discovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712115/launch-specific-app-when-nfc-is-discovered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own application mimeType.

> You could create a custom mimeType in your NDEF message and then create an intent-filter which matches it exactly. This would mean your app would be launched as it is the most specific filter.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.my.app.package.customString" />
> </intent-filter>
> ```

Taken from a previous example I've provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27397938/3312868

Comment: This would only work on android devices I guess. Maybe I should create an external NDEF type with NdefRecord createEternal(string domain, String type, byte [] data). Could this work?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Windows phone but can you not register for a specific mimeType?  If you want to create an external record have a look at Michael Roland's comment above.

Comment: I already solved the problem. You can create an own MIME Type. With this MIME Type you can start your app. Thanks for the help though.